# Easy UML drawing tool on Mac

Tags: osx, drawing

Looking for an easy, cheep UML drawing tool on Mac. Only need to draw text box with border, arrows. Nothing special. Need to be native, no JAVA based cross platform interested me.

Answer (score 1):

Did my UML class last term using nothing but https://draw.io

All web based.  Can save to google docs, etc. or share the drawing.  Export as PNG image, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the UMLet project is still rolling so if Java was ok, you'vde ba able to go that route: free & multi platform, but.. Java-based:

http://www.umlet.com/

Online there are dozens of tools - for example Gliffy:

https://www.gliffy.com/

And for $70.00 there's Star UML, but I didn't see info about whether it was Java based or not:

http://staruml.io/

I *think* Omni-Graffle will suit your needs on this, but... now we're up to $200.00

https://www.omnigroup.com/omnigraffle/compare/

Hope you find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A generic drawing program like Inkscape will more than suffice for drawing text boxes with borders and arrows.

Answer (score 0):

[Scapple](https://www.literatureandlatte.com/scapple/overview) is super easy to use and cheap from the makers of scrivener and there is the  good old original [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/download/macosx.html) but requires XQuarts. and then there is [Runway](http://celestialteapot.com/runway/)

Comment: added Runway a nice dedicated UML editor